# Has won reality shows / won reality shows

Tags: tense, present-tense, past-simple

John has done 3 reality shows so far and he has won 2 of them.

Or

John has done 3 reality shows so far and he won 2 of them.

Should we use present perfect here because we are talking about his achievements or should we use simple past because here we are talking about something that happened at a specific point in the past ( he can't go back to that specific point in that past and win them but he can surely do more reality shows)

Answer (score 1):

Both are understandable of course, but as far as grammatical correctness, I believe the 2nd sentence is correct. The "has" in the first sentence is unnecessary.

Comment: And what's the reason behind it? Could you please explain? Is it because winning/not winning reality shows happened in the past and we can't go to that specific point in time again ?!? Or is it because of some different reason ?!?

Comment: Subrat, this is because you're referring specifically to an event in the past. You are correct. Saying he "has won 2 of them" could imply the event is continuing into the present.

Answer (score 1):

The key words are "so far". They show we are focussing on the present result of past events rather than the events in themselves.

If you wanted to focus on those events in themselves you would begin with "John did..." and go on to "..he won.." but then you could not include the "so far".